# Connecting my React App to a MySQL Database on a PHP Server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, reactjs

I am new to working with data bases. I have a react app that I would like to connect to a MySQL database. The server is not mine but given by a web provider (strato), using PHP.

Is it generally possible to GET and PUT data via react (meaning javascript) to this data base in a way that I normally work with ajax and a restful API?

I really hope this question provides enough information for an answer :)

Comment: so, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to start to be honest. Everything I can find is about how to do it with PHP.

Comment: Where is the API set or where do you plan to locate it? In the web provider server or in the React JS app server?

Comment: Is there an other option than having the API deirectly attached to the SQL data base? Otherwise it needs to be on the server of my web provider.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a code example from https://github.com/numtel/reactive-mysql-example, file index.js. Have a look at that file and settings.js to see how to set up the connection.

```
var results = liveDb.select('select * from players order by score desc', [ {
  table: 'players'
} ]).on('update', function(diff, data){

  var msg = JSON.stringify({
    type: 'diff',
    data: diff
  });

  // Send change to all clients
  connected.forEach(function(conn){
    conn.write(msg);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this. For now I don't really understand how this works but it seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a Javascript (NodeJS express server, NOT a php server)